# CSS - overflow: hidden on <a> tags still result in a clickable <a> tag

Tags: html, css

I have the issue that all my links are clickable when I added `overflow: hidden`. I guess this is expected behavior, but I couldn't figure out how to constantly not allow clicking after the overflow happens.

HTML:

```
<div id="popup" class="new_pages">
    <p>There is/are 3 new article(s) available:
        <a href="www.example.com">Article001</a>,
        <a href="www.example.com">Article002</a>,
        <a href="www.example.com">Article003</a>
        <i onclick="hideMe()" class="fa fa-times close_new_pages" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </p>
</div>
```

The CSS of the `<p>` element looks something like this:

```
div.new_pages p {
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The result looks something like this:

[image: Result]

In this screenshot I am hovering after the X symbol.
I want some option like `display: none`, but only after the overflow.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: i don't see the issue of the overflow ... your link are visible so they are clickable with the overflow or not

Comment: I don't really see the problem when I try to run this myself... Also, `overflow: hidden` applies to scrollbars.

Comment: The issue is that `overflow: hidden` results in hovering the "hidden" part is also clickable.

Comment: are you hiding the element by adding a class ?

Comment: Have you tried to use @media query (e.g. when window smaller than 300px) and add `pointer-events: none;` to the `div.new_pages p` ?

Comment: @AmrLabib The `<div>` element has a fixed width and the styling of my paragraph hides the last link(s) when they are larger then this width.
@Krusader This is not the solution I am searching for. The links should still be clickable I just do not want the link be clickable if you click on the white page where the link is "hidden".